# how to get public Facebook page data (app) of particular login into my android application?

Tags: android, facebook

Am working for facebook public page post. My Customers will login with facebook (inside my application) to link their public pages to my application. With this login is it possible to get customers public pages list created by them in facebook?

As of now i can able to get the user details but not the pages AND events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to my own question after a long research its worked fine with public pages as response from activity result.

```
public class AdminFbLogin extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String userName ="", accessToken = "";
private JSONArray fbPages = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebookLogout();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("loading");
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    try{
    Session.openActiveSession(AdminFbLogin.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user
                    // object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            userName = user.getName();
                            if(fbPages != null ) {
                                returnAccessToken();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
    } catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(AdminFbLogin.this, "Please check your internet connection. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("AdminFBLogin Error",e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);

    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    accessToken =  Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();

    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        new Request(session, "/me/accounts", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                try{
                    GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
                    fbPages = (JSONArray) go.getProperty("data");
                    Log.d("User Response :", response.toString());
                    if(!userName.equals("")) {
                        returnAccessToken();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("JSOn Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
                }
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
    }
}
private void returnAccessToken(){
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("accessToken", accessToken);
    data.putExtra("fbPages", fbPages.toString());
    data.putExtra("userName", userName);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    facebookLogout();
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at the SDK and the tutorials:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/sample-apps